# Validate form-data before uploading image through multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using multer for image upload to my server. I have use express-validator for my fields validations.
I am sending the data as multipart/form-data. Before image upload I want to verify that all the fields validations are performed and after that I upload the image but when I send the data and log it the body is empty but after image upload body has the data

this works

```
    routes.post('/register', upload.single('profile_pic'), validateSignup, signup)
```

but this failed to data

```
routes.post('/register', validateSignup, upload.single('profile_pic'), signup)
```

this is my validation file

```
module.exports = {

    email: {
        in: ['body'],
        errorMessage: 'Please enter a valid email address',
        exists: true,
        isEmail: {
            errorMessage: 'Invalid email format'
        }
    },
    password: {
        in: ['body'],
        isLength: {
            errorMessage: 'Password should be at least 6 chars long',
            options: { min: 6 }
        },
        matches: {
            options: [/^(?=.*[A-Z])/],
            errorMessage: 'At least has a upper letter'
        },
        exists: true
    },
    fullName: {
        in: ['body'],
        errorMessage: 'Please enter a your full name',
        isLength: {
            options: { min: 3, max: 50 }
        },
        exists: true
    }
}
```

> also is it possible to use multer as a function not as a middleware
>   because if it is a function I can call it anywhere